# Stuck in log screen

Tags: login-screen, language-support, crouton

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a chromebook using croutons and got myself stuck in a uncomfortable situation..
I am required to type my English password in log screen to log in however I have currently selected cyrillic keyboard and can't change it back from this screen. I haven't set myself a shortcut for changing languages and I can't find the default shortcut. 
So my question is: given that I have a chromebook keyboard what would be the shortcut for changing language? Or is there any other way to got myself unstuck?

P.s. Restarting the computer and logging to Ubuntu again keeps me in the same screen with the same language set. Maybe there is a third option to restart Ubuntu from Chrome OS terminal so it gives me a fresh start directly to desktop screen from where I can fix my problems?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

The solution I used was to enter chroot terminal via crouton by typing
sudo enter-chroot -n chrootname

Then I changed my password via the command
sudo passwd
to a password that contained only numbers.

I now have my chroot back! Hope I at least helped someone.